# File GeoDatabase Table is too large to export?

Tags: sql-server, export, file-geodatabase, import, arccatalog

We need to query data from the national soils database. The data is in a file geodatabase (which is about 20 GB), but we need to query the data in a SQL Server environment.  In ArcCatalog, I am able to import the tables I need into SQL Server Enterprise 2014 (not SQLServerExpress which has a 10GB limit!) from the file geodatabaes, except for one of them.  This one table is about 12GB in size (and does not contain spatial info).  When I try to import the table, ArcGIS Desktop (Advanced, ArcInfo license) crashes/closes. When I open ArcCatalog again  I can see that the table/structure  is there but it is empty. The file is too large to export to a dbf. How can I get this table OUT of the file geodatabase?

Comment: Sorry not near a computer so can't try this myself.  But I would attempt to append subsets of the table to the empty feature class that has been created

Comment: @tonic do you have access to the Data Interoperability Extension through your ESRI licence?

Comment: There could be some data which is out of bounds or unsupported in the target table. You should verify the column mapping. It's also possible that the version of ArcGIS is incompatible with SQL-Server 2014.

Comment: When you say "ArcGIS Desktop (Advanced, ArcInfo license) crashes/closes" do you mean that you get a Serious Application Error or some other symptom?

Answer (score -1):

I would try the following steps.

1. In ArcCatalog, copy and paste the table in to the new ArcSDE db.
2. Add the table to ArcMap, Open it, on the table window, Options Table export.
3. Try using Model Builder to do it for you.
4. Export your model to Python and try it.
5. Then try all the steps again on a BIG server.
6. Try running a Python script that just grabs the first 10 records and insert them to a table that you built.  If this works just iterate through the rows.  There just might be a data type that 2014 doesn't support.

Do you have a link to this gdb download?